# Laravel Redirect BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

Really not sure what's up here:

http://laravel.io/bin/E8yMx#2

As it's explained, in the `UserController`, when I call a `Redirect::action` to the `SessionController`, I get thrown the exception.

I've tried recompiling but it's still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vit explained, `store` expect `POST` verb. You can use IoC to solve your issue:

```
return App::make('SessionController')->store();
```

**But** I really don't recommend it: what you are trying to do is known as [HMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and as Taylor Otwell said

> This pattern often indicates poor application design, and controllers that are much too complicated

What you should do is to:

> Extract the logic into a third class that can be injected into any controller

Comment: Thanks Razor, Vit Kos. I did some more research and found that it was indeed poor design. Back to the books!

Answer (score 0):

Ow well, you get this type of error because Laravel resourcefull route "store" expects you to receive data from `POST`. I think that redirect is achieved via `headers()` or something like that, so it sends a `GET` request and you get the error. You should use curl in this case, or you should move your common logic elsewhere than controller, for ex : repositories.